# How to use async/await in the best way Protractor

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, async-await, protractor

I was trying to use .then() with my test cases but without success because of strage comportament. I'm trying make tests with google chrome to.

i have the "SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false," in my conf.js file.

**Now the problem:**

When i trying to find some elements in the DOM i has problems...the actual error is:

Failed: Failed: element not interactable

*The CODE (With comments)*

````
    console.log('Testing Pesquisa Assunto ...');

    beforeAll(async function () {
        var teste = await browser.get(browser.params.URL_PROCESSO).then(function () {

        })
    });
    it('Deve escolher um ASSUNTO PRINCIPAL e verificar os resultados', async function () {

        try {
            if ( await browser.findElements(by.id('filtro_assuntos')).toEqual(""));
        } catch{
            let btnMaisFiltros = element(by.id('maisFiltros'))
            let placeAssunto = element(by.css('[placeholder = "Assunto"]'))
            let listAssuntos = element.all(by.className('mat-option-text')).get(2)
            let habilitaAssuntoP = element(by.className('mat-slide-toggle-bar'))
            let aplicar = element(by.className("aplicar"))
            await btnMaisFiltros.click()
            console.log('Entered here 1')
            await placeAssunto.click()
            console.log('Entered here 2') //CANNOT ENTER HERE
            await listAssuntos.click();
            console.log('Entered here 3')
            await habilitaAssuntoP.click()
            console.log('Entered here 4')
            await aplicar.click()
            console.log('Entered here 5')
        }
    })```
````

Comment: Your browser.get needs an `await`. Also expect is a synchronous function so does not need an await but it's argument is async so will like so `expect(await element(by.className('identificacao')).getText()).toContain('Abandono');`

Comment: Thank you @DublinDev . I optmized my code...i put the await in the browser.get like you said but know a ihave another error...what do you thnik about this.